# WPF -How to access the fields present in a template

Tags: c#, wpf

Let me explain so I have a wpf application I used a listBox with a template. This template contains a TextBlock and a ComboBox. When running the application, everything goes well, my list is initialized correctly. But then I would like to retrieve the values ​​of my TextBlock and my comboBox and I don't understand how I can achieve this.

I am attaching the part of my XAML code that deals with this listBox :

```xml
    <ListBox x:Name="ListBoxEnv" Grid.Row="1"
            d:ItemsSource="{d:SampleData ItemCount=5}" Width="460"
            SelectionChanged="ListBoxEnv_SelectionChanged">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <TextBlock x:Name="TxtBlockEnv"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                            Text="{Binding EnvName}"/>
                    <ComboBox x:Name="ComboBoxEnv"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                                ItemsSource="{Binding EnvListValue}"
                                Margin="100,2,0,2" Width="200"
                                SelectionChanged="ComboBoxEnv_SelectionChanged"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

Comment: From where and when do you want to retrieve the values? And from which item?

Comment: You are using binding. Use properties to which you bound controls to get values. What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The `EnvName` property is readonly because it is bound to TextBlock, so you can ignore it. Change binding to: `Text="{Binding EnvName, Mode=OneTime}"` to save the app resources.

However to extract selected environment in every combo in the list you need to add to **ComboBox** template: `SelectedItem={Binding SelectedEnv}` and add new property to `SampleData`

for example

```
public MyEnvironmentClass SelectedEnv {get; set;}
```

Comment: Hello and thank you for answering, I made the modifications you said but in fact I would like to retrieve the values ​​of each Items (TextBlock & ComboBox ) in a function and I don't understand how to use the modifications you told me suggested